# How do you add dollars signs to axis labels in a base graphics plot?

Tags: r, plot, label

I have plotted some numbers in a scatterplot in R and want to add dollar signs to the numbers. How would I do this?

```
x <- = c(100,200,300,400,500)
boxplot(x)
```

Comment: reproducible code is essential here as we don't know what graphics system and function you're attempting to use or what "numbers" are

Comment: I assume you're talking about the numbers on the axis. There's definately a way to do this, but what you're asking for is kind of silly. Try `plot(x,y, ylab="Dollars")`

Comment: $Michael: On the y-axis the numbers are 100,200,300,400,500. I want it to be $100, $200, $300, $400, $500.

Comment: @Damien: This is easy to do in `ggplot`, though I'd have to refresh myself with some R code that I have at home. Do you want answers for other than base graphics?

Answer (score 13):

A quick google search reveals that you need to specify the `labels` argument in the `axis`. Then you can use `sprintf` to control the formatting:

```
boxplot(x, yaxt="n")
axis(2, at=axTicks(2), labels=sprintf("$%s", axTicks(2)))
```

[image]

---

To rotate the labels, use the argument `las`:

```
boxplot(x, yaxt="n")
axis(2, at=axTicks(2), labels=sprintf("$%s", axTicks(2)), las=1)
```

[image]

Comment: @Damien Rotate your labels with the argument `las`. Answer edited.

Comment: To plot the raw data points onto the boxplot, would we have to use ggplot?

Comment: What raw data points? And no, you can't mix base graphics and ggplot graphics. Use either one or the other.

Comment: 100,200,300,400,500. We can't really see these points. Like maybe color the points red and plot them on the boxplot

Comment: Use `points` to do that. Or use a different type of plot to start with.